# Association rules compare with cart

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, apriori, market-basket-analysis

Following is some simple code for apriori

```
import csv
import apriori

with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as fp:
  reader = csv.reader(fp)
  lst1,lst2 = [],[]
  for row in reader:
    others,last = row[:-1],row[-1]
    lst1.append(others)
    lst2.append(last)

L,suppData=apriori.apriori(lst1, minSupport =0.3)
rules = apriori.generateRules(L,suppData, minConf = 0.3)
rules = sorted(rules, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
```

Below is the dataset

```
p1,p2,p3,A
p1,p2,B
p1,p2,C
p1,p2,D
p2,p3,E
p1,p2,p3,F
p1,p3,G
```

Output of rules look like

```
[(frozenset(['p1']), frozenset(['p2']), 0.8333333333333334), (frozenset(['p2']), frozenset(['p1']), 0.8333333333333334), (frozenset(['p3']), frozenset(['p2']), 0.75), (frozenset(['p3']), frozenset(['p1']), 0.75), (frozenset(['p2']), frozenset(['p3']), 0.5), (frozenset(['p1']), frozenset(['p3']), 0.5)]
```

What is the right and efficient way to look into a product cart which is a comma separated string like [p1,p2] and recommend the next 2 best products.

```
cart = ['p1','p2']
recommend=[]
for fz in rules:
     if( ",".join(sorted(fz[0])) == ",".join(cart) ):
        recommend.extend(sorted(fz[1]))
```

The code above does not handle all conditions ..

Answer (score 0):

loop over all your association rules. get those association rules which contain p1 and p2 as the frequent itemset on the left site of the rule, i.e. [p1, p2 -> x]. whereby x is another frequent itemset with maximal two items. you can use associatoin rules like [p1 -> x], [p2 -> x] as well. now get from those association rules these with a maximal support and a maximal confidence. best case, the association rule with the maximal support and confidence is this asscociation rule [p1, p2 -> q1, q2]. q1, q2 are your products to recommend.